# color button C# Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm building a trivia application so i want when i press the button it will be Green if correct and will be Red if not.
my main issue is that wehen i color the button he get larger and looses his grpahic shape.

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (answer == "ב")
        {
            Button2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            Button2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        }
    }
```

[image: before button pressing]
[image: after button pressing]

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button2.Background.SetColorFilter (Android.Graphics.Color.Green, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
```

Actually the button is not getting bigger as it seems is just that the default drawable for the button in Android has paddings, once you change the background setting your color you are removing those and the button is showing its full size.

For Android API 21+ you can also use the `Button2.Background.SetTint();` method.

**UPDATE**

To set the previous ColorFilter

```
var previous = Button2.Background.ColorFilter;

 // Set new color
Button2.Background.SetColorFilter (Android.Graphics.Color.Green, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);

...
...
//Do all you need to do and when ready to set it back

Button2.Background.SetColorFilter(previous);
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to set it back after certain time you can use this code:

```
private async void Button2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var previous = Button2.Background.ColorFilter;

    if (answer == "ב")
    {
        Button2.Background.SetColorFilter (Android.Graphics.Color.Green, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
    }
    else
    {
        Button2.Background.SetColorFilter (Android.Graphics.Color.Red, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
    }

    // This will await 2 seconds before setting the original color.
    await Task.Delay (2000);

   // Using this so we are sure it will run in the UI thread.
    RunOnUiThread (() => {
        Button2.Background.SetColorFilter (previous);
        });
}
```

Comment: how to delete the color filter?

Comment: If you want to get the previous one save it then set it back.. updated answer

Comment: i added it with a timer in other function and its like not updating automaticaly, only if i touch the button or other button